# Crontab not working in Lubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: cron

https://pasteboard.co/I6ohPOy.png

Double clicking on working.sh works.
Typing /home/paul/Desktop/working.sh works.
Rebooting does NOT make it work.

And also, what is the current way of making that command work from a keyboard combination shortcut, like ctrl+alt+9?

Comment: crontab is probably working. Please tell us what you want to do : start the script at boot before login or just after paul user logon ?

Comment: Both. I'd like to know for future reference, but have accomplished this by editing the LDX autostart file automatically created by the Lubuntu monitor GUI wizard - I just put in the XRANDR options I want in there instead of the ones that were there to begin with. It's basically an autorun file that the monitor settings GUI program creates so that the computer maintains the settings last set after reboot. By playing with it, I was able to insert the custom command I need, and that properly sets my monitor settings as needed at reboot, though after I log in.